# Use the pandas pivot index as column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

In the code below I pivot a dataframe using an index `date`. After the pivot, I need to get the month from column `date`. This is my attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : [datetime(2021,3,11), datetime(2021,3,11), datetime(2021,3,11), 
              datetime(2021,3,12), datetime(2021,3,12), datetime(2021,3,12), 
              datetime(2021,3,13), datetime(2021,3,13), datetime(2021,3,13)],
    'field': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'value': [150, 140, 1, 130, 280, 2, 260, 120, 4]
})

print(df)


    date      field value
0   2021-03-11  A   150
1   2021-03-11  B   140
2   2021-03-11  C   1
3   2021-03-12  A   130
4   2021-03-12  B   280
5   2021-03-12  C   2
6   2021-03-13  A   260
7   2021-03-13  B   120
8   2021-03-13  C   4


df_pivoted = df.pivot(index='date', columns='field', values='value')
print(df_pivoted)

field       A     B   C
date            
2021-03-11  150  140  1
2021-03-12  130  280  2
2021-03-13  260  120  4

df_pivoted['month'] = df_pivoted['date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

I get an error, as the `date` field is not a column, but I need to use it:

```
KeyError: 'date'
```

Why can't I use a column that's also an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is the index, so you have to get the months from the index:

```
df_pivoted['month'] = df_pivoted.index.month
```

Output:

```
field         A    B  C  month
date                          
2021-03-11  150  140  1      3
2021-03-12  130  280  2      3
2021-03-13  260  120  4      3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

extract month first, set index, stack and unstack

```
df['month']=df.date.dt.month
df.set_index(['date','field','month']).stack().unstack('field', 'month').droplevel(level=2).reset_index()df['month']=df.date.dt.month
```

or

```
df['month']=df.date.dt.month

df_pivoted = df.pivot(index=['date','month'], columns=['field'], values='value').reset_index()
```

Outcome in both cases

```
field       date  month    A    B  C
0     2021-03-11      3  150  140  1
1     2021-03-12      3  130  280  2
2     2021-03-13      3  260  120  4
```